# How is 'relative' positioning placing the tooltip at the correct position?

Tags: css, css-position, positioning

[Here's](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/) an example of a CSS tooltip. The author positions the toolip relatively.

```
.tooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
```

However, the [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) says,

> **Relative**. This type of positioning is probably the most confusing and
>   misused. What it really means is "relative to itself". If you set
>   position: relative; on an element but no other positioning attributes
>   (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at
>   all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as position:
>   static; But if you DO give it some other positioning attribute, say,
>   top: 10px;, it will shift it's position 10 pixels DOWN from where it
>   would NORMALLY be. I'm sure you can imagine, the ability to shift an
>   element around based on it's regular position is pretty useful. I find
>   myself using this to line up form elements many times that have a
>   tendency to not want to line up how I want them to.
>
> There are two
>   other things that happen when you set position: relative; on an
>   element that you should be aware of. One is that it introduces the
>   ability to use z-index on that element, which doesn't really work with
>   statically positioned elements. Even if you don't set a z-index value,
>   this element will now appear on top of any other statically positioned
>   element. You can't fight it by setting a higher z-index value on a
>   statically positioned element. The other thing that happens is it
>   limits the scope of absolutely positioned child elements. Any element
>   that is a child of the relatively positioned element can be absolutely
>   positioned within that block. This brings up some powerful
>   opportunities which I talk about here.

What I understand is that, without modifiers like `top`, `left` etc. `relative` is equivalent to `static` and goes with the flow of the page. Then how's the tooltip being displayed at the correct position, i.e. above the hyperlink? Shouldn't it appear at the end of the page instead?

Answer (score 3):

The CSS you provided for tooltip is not complete. I think you saw it in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp). But note that there are two elements for it: a parent element with `.tooltip` class and a child element (actual tooltip text) inside it with `.tooltiptext` class.

the parent element has `position: relative` without any `top`, `left` ... positions which acts as you said as a static element in its original (normal) place. But the child tooltiptext inside it has a `position: absolute` which is why it is seperated from normal text flow and put over them.

Here is a sample:

```css
.tooltip {
    /* this is just to add meaning for position:absolute of .tooltiptext */
    position: relative; 
  
    color: navy;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%;
    left: 10%;
    
    /* style the tooltip */
    min-width: 50px;
    background-color: #ff9;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px 10px 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  
    visibility: hidden;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span>Sample: </span>

<span class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</span>
```